# Не работает поиск php sql LIKE %word

Tags: php, sql

Всем привет.
Когда в базе данных ищу таким образом:

```
SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `en` LIKE '%A%'
```

Так все результаты выводятся.

А когда так:

```
SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `en` LIKE '%A'
```

Без % в конце, то почему то результатов нет.

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том, что поиск происходит таким образом:

Найди все слова, которые имеют любые символы и количество, но слово обязательно должно **заканчиваться** на букву "A".  Скорее всего таких в базе нет ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Принял, спасибо :)